# Regarding a contour plot

Tags: graphics3d, plotting

I have a function $ f(x, y) = \sin x\ \cos y\ \mathrm e^{x + y} $ (just an example) such that $ x + y \le 1 $ (both $ x $ and $ y $ are positive and $ 0 < x \le 1 $ and $ 0 < y \le 1 $).

I want to make a contour plot such that the contraint $ x + y \le 1 $ is taken into consideration. By this I mean that for the value of $ x = x_0 $ the values of $ f $ should be such that $ y = 1 - x_0 $.

Comment: Please phrase your question *as a question* and provide code showing where you are getting stuck.

Answer (score 2):

```
Plot3D[Sin[x] Cos[y] Exp[x + y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1},
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, x + y < 1],
 MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> 5,
 MeshStyle ->Directive[Thickness[0.01],Red]]
```

[image]

or

```
ContourPlot[Sin[x] Cos[y] Exp[x + y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1},
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, x + y < 1],
 MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> 5,
 MeshStyle -> Directive[Thickness[0.01], Red]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @David G. Stork. Could you suggest some nice PlotLegend?

Comment: Depends what you're trying to show:  `PlotLegend-> "my legend"` or "Cost of soybeans in 1974" or whatever...